# Getting [makefile:36:debug] Error1 error when try to run a project on qt creator

Tags: qt-creator

In the Kits tab, it showing warning at gcc compiler

[image]

Can anyone have answer, which compiler and kit is compatible with qt version 5.9.5?

Comment: If you check the error message it says: `... x86-windows-msvc2015-pe-64bit`  that indicates that you have downloaded Qt for msvc 2015, so you must install msvc 2015. Another option is to use the Qt installer for mingw

Comment: i have installed msvc 2015 earlier

Comment: go to the Kit tab and select that kit, then in the Compiler section use the correct one